# Define business methods usable by linq to entity and linq to objects

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I use in my project a lot of LINQ queries and business methods.
To allow these business method to be used from an Iqueryable :

- I defined UDF functions in SQL Server (with the needed parameters)
- Add this UDF to the EDMX model of the application
- And make a gateway between UDF and LinQ with a method like this in a
  partial class who inherits from the dbcontext :

  ```
    [EdmFunction("MyProject.Store", "GetTaxesOfProduct")]
     public static Decimal GetTaxesOfProduct(Decimal amount, Int32 TaxMethod)
     {
         throw new NotSupportedException("Not direct access possible, use with E-SQL or LINQ");
     }
  ```

This works perfectly for IQueryable.
But the problem is that, to use this method from a simple object (not linked to a database record), i need to make something creepy like this :

```
var query = from foo in context.JustATable select context.GetTaxesOfProduct(15.55, 3);
```

And recently i came across this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics.aspx who explain how, with expression, you can make a method who is usable from C# objects and IQueryable

So, with expression, is it possible to make business methods like my method but without the use of UDF and just expressions ?

Thank you by advance !

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the content of your UDF. Expression can work only with entities defined in your model and use only operations provided by Entity Framework provider for your database. So if you use any complex SQL statement with not supported equivalent for LINQ or non mapped features inside your UDF it will not work.